# Click event is not working in React js

Tags: reactjs

This is my response:

> {Ether|ether} is the historian of the {Jaredites|jaredites}.

I am using the `replace()` function to replace this **{Ether|ether}**

> description =  text.narration.description.replace(/{(.*?)\|(.*?)}/g,
>   `<a className="peoplelink" id="$2"
>   onClick={this.demoButton.bind(this)}>$1</a>`);
>
> description = React.createElement('span', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
>   __html: description } });

Afterwards the click event is not working and produces this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

[image: Inspected HTML code]

Comment: Please provide the component code where `demoButton` and `description` is used.

Comment: @Vipul Singh, description is only a simple variable

Comment: what happens when You click that? Maybe use defaultPrevented to prevent default behavior of <a>

Comment: @MichalCholewiński I have got an error after the click:" Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick"

Comment: @GouravKumar have you done  demoButton(event){ event.preventDefault(); //then your code}  ??

Comment: and in the browser click-event is in the string like this:-  <a onclick=" {this.demoButton.bind(this)}">Ether</a>

Comment: I'm almost sure that it takes event in parameter so You should be able to do this

Comment: this is my function :-      demoButton(event) {
        console.log("Demo Button");
    }

Comment: @GouravKumar before console.log("Demo Button"); perform event.preventDefault()

Comment: @MichalCholewiński after using  event.preventDefault() same error is occured  " TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick "

Comment: Just check this site https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html maybe will help

Comment: @MichalCholewiński, in a simple way it working but I have replaced my response using replace function, I am adding click event dynamically. Replace function return a simple string for convert string to Html(react element )  I used " dangerouslySetInnerHTML" this after converting, it create html and click event is not working

Comment: after converting it create  HTML like this :- <a  onclick="{this.demoButton.bind(this)}">Ether</a> and here is you can see onclick event is in the string  onclick="{this.demoButton.bind(this)}" like this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are calling but as example you can refer this code:

option 1:- **(recommended)**

```
constructor() {
this.applyClick = this.applyClick.bind(this);
}

render() {
<a onClick={this.applyClick}>Apply</a>
}
```

option 2:- 
    **No need to bind or define in constructor**

```
render() {
<a onClick={this.applyClick.bind(this)}>Apply</a>
}
```

Comment: @agarwal this is not the main reason we can bind direct in onClick event

Answer (score 0):

```
applyClick(){

   console.log("applied");
}


render(){ 

return (
   <div>
      <a onClick={this.applyclick.bind(this)}</a>
  </div>
 );
```

}

Comment: @chinna, I think " href " event is used for routing

Comment: yeah.. I changed to onClick method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.